# Centralizar imagem verticalmente dentro de uma div

Tags: css, div

Preciso centralizar imagens dentro de uma `div`.
Consigo fazer isso horizontalmente com `text-align:center;`, porém quero centralizar **verticalmente**.
Tentei `vertical-align: middle;` e `display: table-cell;` e não funcionou.

Existe alguma outra solução? Se possível, somente usando CSS.

Comment: Prevejo que essa será uma dúvida muito comum no futuro, então esta pergunta é uma boa candidata para ser protegida.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar mais algumas informações. Por exemplo, seu div tem largura e altura fixas?.
Alguns trechos de html/css também seriam bons.

Comment: Esta questão está resolvida? Se estiver aceite a resposta que a soluciona.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caso não seja necessário um suporte para o Internet Explorer 8 ou o projeto seja mais flexível também é possível utilizar o seguinte código:

```
.vertical-align {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Adicionar os prefixos dos navegadores */
}
```

**Fonte -** http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Também vale lembrar que o uso do `display:table` não funciona com `float`.

Uma outra solução, para quem precise dar suporte abaixo do Internet Explorer 8:

```
.vertical-align {
    display: block;
}

.vertical-align > div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: inherit;
    clear: ~'expression(style.marginTop = "" + (offsetHeight < parentNode.offsetHeight ? parseInt((parentNode.offsetHeight - offsetHeight) / 2) + "px" : "0"), style.clear = "none", 0)';
}
```

Outra solução caso o suporte ao Internet Explorer 6 seja necessário:

```
.vertical-align {
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-align > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.vertical-align > div > div {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}
```

**Fonte -** http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Answer (score 11):

Isso deve resolver o seu problema:

```css
div img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Dei voteup pois essa é a maneira certa de se fazer, sei que é obvio, mais isso só vai funcionar se o `width` da div for maior que a imagem.

Comment: O alinhamento horizontal é realmente a melhor forma de fazer, mas alinhamento vertiacal tem que ser em 2 nível, um nível com 'display:table;' e outro nível com 'displau:table-cell' aí sim pode ser utilizado o 'vertical-align: middle;'

Answer (score 9):

Embora faça algum tempo que foi feito essa pergunta; estarei mostrar uma forma fácil de centralizar imagens usando `flex-box`, para ajudar os que precisarem.

Insira uma classe na `div` e coloque a tag `img` dentro da `div`, como mostrado abaixo:

```
<div class="centralizarImagem">
    <img src="algumaImagem.jpg" alt="Alguma Imagem" width="400" height="190" />
</div>
```

No CSS insira:

```
.centralizarImagem { 
    display:         flex;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Garante compatibilidade com navegador Safari. */

    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Se você quiser estudar mais sobre `flex-box`, no site [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) está disponibilizado um guia mais completo.

Comment: A única resposta/sugestão que funcionou para mim (março/2020)

Answer (score 5):

O que está faltando é o `display:table;` no container da **div** que está com `display: table-cell;` colocando isso vai funcionar perfeitamente.
veja o exemplo:
CSS:

```css
#container {
 width: 200px; 
 height: 150px; 
 border: 1px solid #c30;
 background: #ffe;
 position: relative;
 display:table; 
 }
#container p {
 *position: absolute; 
 top: 50%; 
 display: table-cell; 
 vertical-align: middle;
 }
#container span {
 display:block; 
 *position: relative; 
 top: -50%;
 }
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
    <p><span>Texto no meio da DIV</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

A forma mais simples que conheço e tenho certeza que não falha é essa

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#container img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Esta é uma forma cross-browser de se fazer o alinhamento independente de a imagem ser paisegem ou retrato.

Answer (score 2):

Para centralizar uma imagem dentro de uma *div*, você precisa, primeiramente, colocar a *div* com `position: relative` e a imagem com `position: absolute`.

Após isso,`transform: translate(-50%,-50%)`, juntamente com `top 50%` e `left 50%`, como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo:

```
div{  
    position: relative;  
    width: 170px; // Largura da DIV  
    height: 155px; // Altura da DIV  
    overflow: hidden; // Para que as partes da imagem maior que as widht e height não apareçam  
}

img{  
    position: absolute;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    top: 50%;  
    left: 50%;  
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente com `line-height:`.

Exemplo:

```
line-height: 40px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Aqui uma forma:

[**EXEMPLO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tableless/dNjCK/light/)

HTML:

```html
<div>
  Este div está no centro!
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px; /* metade da largura */
  margin-top: -100px; /* metade da altura */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Fonte: http://tableless.com.br/centralizando-um-objeto-na-horizontal-e-vertical-com-css/

Comment: Isso também vai funcionar com imagens de tamanhos diferentes?

Comment: Sim, basta definir o tamanho da imagem e colocar as margin negativa, por exemplo, se definir width: 500px e height: 100px. Então a margin-left deve ser a metade de width negativo no caso magin-left: -250px e  o margin-top deve ser a metade do tamanho de height negativo, no caso margin-top: -50px

Comment: Amigo, quando uso margens negativas, sinto que estou fazendo algo errado, hehe.

Comment: Tudo bem, só citei uma de N formas de fazer o que quer.

Answer (score 0):

Se seu div e sua imagem tiverem um heigth definido, você pode fazer isso:

```
.img { 
 height: 200px; /* Altura da imagem */
 position:relative;
 margin-top: 50%;
 top: -100px; /* Negatico da metade da altura da imagem */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado à todos pela ajuda.

Eu consegui da seguinte forma.

```
.produtosListagemImagemFix {
display: table-cell;
height: 286px;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 253px;}
```

Assim funcionou. 100% alinhado!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que com `display:grid` seja a forma mais fácil! Deixei os comentário no CSS

**OBS:** Funciona do IE10 para frente! https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.grid {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center; /* centraliza na vertical e horizontal */
    /* align-items: center; se quiser centralizar apenas na vertical */
}
.centro {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="centro">margin: auto;</div>
</div>
```