# Centralizar elemento em uma página

Tags: css

Tenho uma página e login para desenvolver e há um logo bem no centro da página.
Ok, centralizei da seguinte forma:

```
bg{
    background-image: url("../imagens/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1138px;
}
   .logo {
    background-image: url("../imagens/logo.png");
    width: 140px;
    height: 101px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Coloquei um `position:absolute` e gostaria de saber se há outra forma, pois, caso contrário, tudo que vier abaixo dessa div `.logo` terei que colocar **position** e não quero isso.

HTML:

```
<div class="bg">        
<div class="logo"></div>
</div>
```

Imagem demonstrativa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: Será que nenhuma dessas técnicas (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5225/centralizar-imagem-dentro-de-uma-div) resolve o problema?

Comment: O que preciso é um pouco diferente dessa vez. Eu consigo centralizar e trabalhar o resto do site perfeitamente, só que preferiria não usar `position`, pois tenho que ficar definindo `top` de cada elemento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sem mexer na *markup* e sem mexer no CSS, só precisas trocar o `position:absolute;` para o `position:relative;` no elemento com a classe `.logo`.

Com posição absoluta: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/7zmkdj8p/)

[image: Problema com elemento ao centro via "position:absolute"]

Resolvido com posição relativa: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/7zmkdj8p/1/)

[image: Elemento ao centro via "position:relative"]

Efetivamente a solução passa por manter o elemento no seu lugar em relação ao fluxo do documento, o que permite que os elementos que se seguem se posicionem após o espaço ocupado pelo teu elemento `.logo`. Ver [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38218/223) para informação completa sobre `position` em CSS.

Com posicionamento absoluto estás a retirar o elemento do fluxo normal do documento o que te obriga a alterar a *markup* ou a posicionar absolutamente todos os restantes elementos.

---

```css
bg{
    background-image: url("../imagens/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1138px;
}
.logo {
    background-color:red;
    width: 140px;
    height: 101px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">        
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <form>FORM</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Resposta perfeita, era exatamente isso que eu estava precisando. Eu pensava que por padrão, a div era `position:relative`.

Comment: Por defeito é `static` por isso é que o `top` e `left` não "funcionam" sem definires pelo menos `position:relative`.