# Centralizar conteúdo da div no AlertController

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo

```
 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  message: '<div><img height="50" src="assets/imgs/success.png"></div><div>' +
  '<p>Cadastrado com sucesso!!!</p>' +
  '</div>',
   buttons: [{
    text: 'OK',
    handler: data => {
      console.log('Ok clicked');
    }
  }]
});
alert.present();
```

Onde estou usando importando o `AlertController` desta forma:

```
import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

Veja a imagem como fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de centralizar o conteúdo do `AlertController`, porém tentei de algumas formas mas não funciona, como por exemplo [desta forma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5228/35406), mas não reconhece.

Existe alguma forma de centralizar conteúdo da `div` no `AlertController`?

Comment: Como exatamente gostaria que ficasse? Você tem 2 elementos divs 1 elemento img e um elemento p, não entendi qual exatamente quer alinhar no centro, é centro vertical horizontal ou ambos?

Comment: @MagicHat alinhar tudo. Aliás, menos o botão OK. Ou talvez também. huehe

Comment: Sei lá tenta : <div style="width:70%;float:none;display:block;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;"><img height="50" src="assets/imgs/success.png">' +
  '<p>Cadastrado com sucesso!!!</p></div>'...

Comment: @MagicHat já tinha tentando assim, mas não funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa definir uma classe css pro seu AlertController:

Exemplo:

```
 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      message: '<div><img height="80" src="http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg"></div><div>' +
      '<p>Cadastrado com sucesso!!!</p>' +
      '</div>',
      buttons: ['Dismiss'],
      cssClass: 'custom-alert',
    });
    alert.present();
 }
```

Repare que na criação do alerta eu tenho um atributo `cssClass` no qual passo uma classe css. O css ficaria dessa forma:

```
page-home {}

.custom-alert .alert-message{
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**OBS:.** Note que o css não estão dentro da estilização da página, ou seja, ele tem que ser separado pois o componente alerta não é renderizado dentro da sua página:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse exemplo usei um `text-align: center` para alinhar os componentes, mas nada lhe impede de customizar o css do jeito que você preferir.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: hahaha... eu tava colocando a classe dentro da `page-home`! Por isso não estava funcionando. Você pode complementar sua resposta falando porque deve ficar fora da `page-home` no css? Deu certo aqui. =D

Comment: @acklay opa, posso sim.

Answer (score -3):

Certamente cheguei tarde... mas encontrei esta resposta na documentação oficial: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert:
"Observação
Se você estiver criando um aplicativo Ionic Angular, os estilos precisam ser adicionados a um arquivo de folha de estilo global.". Veja que isso se refere ao component alert.